# Restart machine using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am running the below code but the restart is not working. My intention was to run restart command parallelly on all remote machines at once.

```
$YourFile = gc "machinelst.txt"
$username = "user1"
$password = "pass1"
$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred  = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpw)

foreach ($computer in $YourFile)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock { Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force } -AsJob
     
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove -ErrorAction Stop for read error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have remove the -ErrorAction Stop and run the script again.It is not restarting

Comment: what is your errors text

Comment: Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
76     Job76           RemoteJob       Failed        False           RemoteHost1      Restart-Computer -Com...
78     Job78           RemoteJob       Failed        False           RemoteHost2      Restart-Computer -Com...
80     Job80           RemoteJob       Failed        False           RemoteHost3      Restart-Computer -Com...          This is the output

Comment: remove -AsJob and give me your error

Comment: I want to run the restart parallel, not one after the other. Your suggestion might be sequential run is it?

Comment: it's just for read error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (you will can add -asjob if it's work) :

```
$username = "yourdomain\user1"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass1" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

get-content "machinelst.txt" | %{
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $_ -Authentication default -Credential $cred

}
```

if you want use job, you can do it :

```
$listjob=@()

get-content "machinelst.txt" | %{
$listjob+=Restart-Computer -ComputerName $_ -Authentication default -Credential $cred -AsJob
}

$listjob | Wait-Job -Timeout 30

$listjob | %{

    if ($_.State -eq 'Failed' )
    {
      Receive-Job -Job $_ -Keep
    }
   
}
```

Comment: ConvertTo-SecureString : Input string was not in a correct format.
At restart.ps1:14 char:26  $password = "pass1" | ConvertTo-SecureString

Comment: try with this change

Comment: ok it seems like working now. One thing i want to know, this script will execute the restart parallely on all remote servers at once? or will it run sequential?.

Comment: You can use the "-asjob" command to initiate parallel restarts, but restarting either takes time depending on the remote server. There may be gaps of a few seconds I think.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like its the output from Get-Job - could you try Receive-Job $id (Receive-Job 80).

Should give you the actual exception.

Answer (score 1):

This likely runs in parallel just like invoke-command does with an array of computernames:

```
restart-computer computer01,computer02,computer03,computer04,computer05
```

Or this.  It takes a couple minutes for the winrm service to come back, but they all seem to reboot at the same time.

```
$c = get-credential
$list = 1..10 | % tostring computer00
restart-computer $list -wait -protocol wsman -cr $c
```